# Asterisk reached but can't register

Tags: asterisk

I'm new at asterisk and following asterisk example:
sip.conf

```
[general]
transport=udp

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[demo-alice](friends_internal)
secret=verysecretpassword 
qualify=yes
; put a strong, unique password here instead
qualify=yes
[demo-bob](friends_internal)

secret=othersecretpassword ; put a strong, unique password here instead
```

And this is pjsip.conf:

```
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0

;Templates for the necessary config sections

[endpoint_internal](!)
type=endpoint
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw

[auth_userpass](!)
type=auth
auth_type=userpass

[aor_dynamic](!)
type=aor
max_contacts=1

;Definitions for our phones, using the templates above

[demo-alice](endpoint_internal)
auth=demo-alice
aors=demo-alice
[demo-alice](auth_userpass)
password=unsecurepassword ; put a strong, unique password here instead
username=demo-alice
[demo-alice](aor_dynamic) 

[demo-bob](endpoint_internal)
auth=demo-bob
aors=demo-bob
[demo-bob](auth_userpass)
password=unsecurepassword ; put a strong, unique password here instead
username=demo-bob
[demo-bob](aor_dynamic)
```

I used `Ekiga` softphone to login `demo-alice` account:

```
ubuntu*CLI> 
    -- Added contact 'sip:demo-alice@192.168.0.217:5060' to AOR 'demo-alice' with expiration of 3600 seconds
  == Contact demo-alice/sip:demo-alice@192.168.0.217:5060 has been created
  == Endpoint demo-alice is now Reachable
    -- Contact demo-alice/sip:demo-alice@192.168.0.217:5060 is now Unknown.  RTT: 0.000 msec
[Oct 25 16:40:10] WARNING[16587]: res_pjsip_pubsub.c:3134 pubsub_on_rx_publish_request: No registered publish handler for event presence
[Oct 25 16:40:10] WARNING[16587]: res_pjsip_pubsub.c:3134 pubsub_on_rx_publish_request: No registered publish handler for event presence
ubuntu*CLI> sip show peers
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status      Description                      
demo-alice                (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored                                  
demo-bob                  (Unspecified)                            D  Auto (No)  No             0        Unmonitored                                  
2 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 2 offline]
ubuntu*CLI>
```

`Ekiga` show I already registered but `Asterisk` server didn't.
It said: `Reached` but status is `Unknown` or `Unmonitored` with `Unspecified` IP. Help!!!
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and `Asterisk 13.11.2` in Ubuntu server 16.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You propably want to use chan_sip OR chan_pjsip.

Check modules.conf to prevent one of them from loading...

In your CLI it seems, ekiga is registered on chan_pjsip.

So try "pjsip show endpoints" (-> chan_pjsip) instead of "sip show peers" (-> chan_sip).